# Script to not let certain characters in an input box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using this script to disallow users to insert `| < > / \ : * ? \ " ^` into an input box on a form on an aspx c# website. However this only works for IE or Chrome. I Was wondering if anyone could provide insight as to why its not working in firefox?

```
<script type="text/jscript">

    $('input').bind('keypress', function(event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("[|<>/\\\\:*?\"^]");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key) == false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Seach cannot contain the following characters: \n \\ / : * ? \" < > |");
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you've declared it incorrectly.

change this

```
<script type="text/jscript">
```

to the correct:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

or you can omit the type completely as JavaScript is the default:

```
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Asside from what **scunliffe** posted, this is probably not what you want:

```
if (!regex.test(key) == false)
  --^--                 --^--
```

You're negating twice. Maybe you want this:

```
if (!regex.test(key))
```

That makes more sense. `test` is falsy so no need to compare to bool.